# Search in database table using FlexibleSearchService Hybris

Tags: java, spring, sap-commerce-cloud, flexible-search

I try to make a DAO what needs to search for an item in the database table. I'm pretty new in Hybris so I don't know what is wrong exactly here (query or my junk code). That is the error that appears in cmd.

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [DispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.exceptions.FlexibleSearchException: SQL search error - enable the property 'flexible.search.exception.show.query.details' for more details] with root cause
> java.sql.SQLException: Invalid value for getLong()

That is my DAO class implementation

```
@Component(value = "arbRedirectHttpTypeDao")
public class ArbRedirectHttpTypeDaoImpl implements ArbRedirectHttpTypeDao {

private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(ArbRedirectHttpTypeDaoImpl.class);

@Autowired
private FlexibleSearchService flexibleSearchService;

public FlexibleSearchService getFlexibleSearchService() {
    return flexibleSearchService;
}

public void setFlexibleSearchService(FlexibleSearchService flexibleSearchService) {
    this.flexibleSearchService = flexibleSearchService;
}

@Override
public ArbRedirectHttpTypeModel findNewUrlByOldUrl(String oldUrl) {

    final String query = "SELECT {"+ ArbRedirectHttpTypeModel.NEWURL +"}"
            + " FROM {"+ ArbRedirectHttpTypeModel._TYPECODE +"} WHERE {"
            + ArbRedirectHttpTypeModel.OLDURL +"}=?oldUrl";

    final FlexibleSearchQuery flexibleSearchQuery = new FlexibleSearchQuery(query);

    flexibleSearchQuery.addQueryParameter("oldUrl", oldUrl);

    final List<ArbRedirectHttpTypeModel> locationsByCode = flexibleSearchService
            .<ArbRedirectHttpTypeModel> search(flexibleSearchQuery)
            .getResult();

    LOG.info("-------------------------------------" + locationsByCode.get(0));
    if (locationsByCode != null && !locationsByCode.isEmpty())
    {
        return locationsByCode.get(0);
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }

}
}
```

And here I try to call it

```
 @Resource
 private ArbRedirectHttpTypeDao arbRedirectHttpTypeDao;
ArbRedirectHttpTypeModel arbRedirectHttpTypeModel = arbRedirectHttpTypeDao.findNewUrlByOldUrl("/Aapuvdc");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use "SELECT {"+ ArbRedirectHttpTypeModel.PK +"}". It will return object and you can get all attribute by getter

Answer (score 1):

```
"SELECT {"+ ArbRedirectHttpTypeModel.NEWURL +"}"
```

In here you're trying to return the `NEWURL` of the model, which I assume will be a string. Flexible search query returns the pk from the item and casts it to hybris model by default. Instead try to reorganize your query to select the pk

```
"SELECT {"+ ArbRedirectHttpTypeModel.PK +"}"
```

Or you can leave the query as it is and set the return type of the query with `FlexibleSearchQuery.setResultClassList(classList);` such as:

```
flexibleSearchQuery.setResultClassList(Collections.singletonList(String.class));
```

You don't have to cast `.search()` to `ArbRedirectHttpTypeModel` either. You can just go with

```
SearchResult<String> result = flexibleSearchService.search(flexibleSearchQuery).getResult();
return result.getCount() > 0 ? result.getResult().get(0) : null;
```

Comment: I put some code below you replay, what I  result is the only the PK, what can I do to get a specific column item?

Comment: don't use setResultClassList and return the result as SearchResult< ArbRedirectHttpTypeModel>